# How to solve a problem with Ant Design. Nothing is displayed, my "app" div is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

After installing Ant Design and create this component, nothing is displayed. Blank page and the `<div id="app"></div>` is empty in the browser.

I also tried to make the same component with material ui but the problem is the same nothing is displayed. I do not understand.

Ant Design version : 3.22.0
React version : 16.0.0

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Form, Icon, Input, Button, Select
} from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { socket } from '../app';
import { setRoom } from '../actions/game';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './CreateGamePage.scss';

export class CreateGamePage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            room: "",
            category: "0",
            difficulty: "any",
            questionCount: "5",
            error: "",
        }
    }

    onRoomChange = (e) => {
        const room = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ room });
    };

    onCategoryChange = (e) => {
        const category = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ category })
    }

    onDifficultyChange = (e) => {
        const difficulty = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ difficulty });
    }

    onCountChange = (e) => {
        const questionCount = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ questionCount });
    }
    submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const config = {
            room: this.state.room,
            category: this.state.category,
            difficulty: this.state.difficulty,
            questionCount: this.state.questionCount
        };

        socket.emit("createRoom", config, (res) => {
            if (res.code === "success") {
                this.setState({ error: "" })
                this.props.setRoom(this.state.room);
                this.props.history.push("/lobby");
            } else {
                this.setState({ error: res.msg })
            }
        });

    };

    render() {
        const InputGroup = Input.Group;
        const { Option } = Select;
        return (
            <div className="CreateGamePage">
                {
                    this.props.type === "" && <Redirect to="/" />
                }
                <div className="form-container">
                        <Form className="form" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                            {this.state.error && <p className="errormessage">{this.state.error}</p>}
                            <Form.Item>
                                {getFieldDecorator('room', {
                                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Merci de renseigner un mot de passe !' }],
                                })(
                                    <div>
                                    <h2 className="Title">Créer une nouvelle partie</h2>
                                    <Input prefix={<Icon type="usergroup-add" />} type="text" name="room" value={this.state.room} onChange={this.onRoomChange} placeholder="Mot de passe du salon" />
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                                {getFieldDecorator('category', {
                                    rules: [{ required: false, message: 'Merci de renseigner une catégorie !' }],
                                })(
                                    <InputGroup compact>
                                        <Select defaultValue={"0"} onChange={this.onCategoryChange}>
                                            <Option key={"0"} value="0">Any Categories</Option>
                                            {
                                                this.props.categories.map((category) => {
                                                    return <Option key={category.id} value={category.id}>{category.name}</Option>
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </Select>
                                    </InputGroup>
                                )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                                {getFieldDecorator('difficulty', {
                                    rules: [{ required: false, message: 'Merci de renseigner une difficulté !' }],
                                })(
                                    <InputGroup compact>
                                        <Select defaultValue={"any"} onChange={this.onDifficultyChange}>
                                            <Option key={"any"} value={"any"}>Any Difficulty</Option>
                                            <Option key="easy" value="easy">Easy</Option>
                                            <Option key="medium" value="medium">Medium</Option>
                                            <Option key="hard" value="hard">Hard</Option>
                                        </Select>
                                    </InputGroup>
                                )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                                {getFieldDecorator('questionCount', {
                                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Merci de renseigner le nombre de questions !' }],
                                })(
                                    <InputGroup compact>
                                        <Select defaultValue="5" onChange={this.onCountChange}>
                                            <Option key="5" value="5">5 Questions</Option>
                                            <Option key="10" value="10">10 Questions</Option>
                                            <Option key="15" value="15">15 Questions</Option>
                                        </Select>
                                    </InputGroup>
                                )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                                    Créer
                                </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    categories: state.game.categories,
    type: state.type
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    setRoom: (room) => dispatch(setRoom(room))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateGamePage);
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: No, unfortunately no error. I do not know if it helps but I use webpack

Comment: Where are you actually rendering the components to the DOM?  Are you able to get non-AntD JSX to appear?

Comment: Look at here : https://pastebin.com/9L6LinVr

Comment: And this is AppRouter component : https://pastebin.com/WNmpuWRU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this, I think:

```
ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("app"));
```

You're rendering your JSX to an element with an id of app, not `root`.

Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: sorry for the error. The div id is "app" not root !

Comment: Ah, well if there are no error messages and no markup, I'd guess it's simply not being rendered.  Are you using create-react-app?  If not, did you make sure to link the script file that does the rendering in your HTML?

Comment: Also you're using a newer version of AntD and a somewhat older version of React, maybe try updating the package as well.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you gave me ! I will try to update the package.

Comment: Here is the link of my repository : https://github.com/alexandrebuisson/quiz-experience

Comment: If you run ```yarn dev-server``` or ```npm run dev-server```, the app is definitely rendered, but there are a host of unrelated errors in the console from your components that you will need to resolve before it does so successfully

Comment: By updating react and correcting 2 errors the code runs correctly. Thanks a lot for your help :)